# configure Rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have no clue how emails works, what i want is a notification email, to send some sort of email for verification like most forums or webpages do.

I have the following mailer class

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "myemail@gmail.com"

  def verification_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail( :to => user.email, :subject => "Notification")
  end
end
```

then i perform `UserMailer.verification_email( user).deliver` to send the email
the problem is i am not receiving any email, the `user.email` and `myemail@gmail` have all the correct value on my code, however i am supose i have to configure something in order to send emails from my gmail account with rails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html - See section 5, Action Mailer Configuration.  This will show you how to set up ActionMailer to use Gmail as you mail server.  That should get you up and running.